# On what content do I replace a fragment from within a tab when using the FragmentTabsPager Compatability Library Example?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I will attempt to keep it short and to the point.

Observe the screenshot below :
[image]

How do I implement a way that, when I press an item on this ListView, the fragment is replaced with a new fragment with data of the corresponding player? Am I supposed to replace the content of the FrameLayout tabcontent? and if so, how do I make sure that the ViewPager still remains functional?

the XML of the "Base Activity":

```
<TabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And this is the onActivityCreated :

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstance);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);


        listView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lv_federations);
        listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (savedInstance == null)
        {
            new PullFederationDataTask().execute();

        }       

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) 
            {
                // Replace Fragment
            }
        });
    }
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the replacement of the Fragment in a `onItemClickListener` as in your code, since I'm struggling with the same problem and haven't found a proper solution yet.

If you implement your player list by extending a `ListFragment`, you can replace the current fragment by a new fragment that displays the details of a player using [fragment transactions](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions) (or you could start a new activity, but I'll discuss fragment transactions in this answer).

To replace the fragment, you can create a new fragment in the `onListItemClick` method that takes the ID of the clicked list item as argument for the fragment's constructor:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    // Here I assume that the fragment containing the player details
    // is called PlayerDetailFragment.
    // The id of the item that was clicked is passed to the fragment's constructor.
    Fragment newFragment = new PlayerDetailFragment(id);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack.
    // android.R.id.content refers to the id of the root ViewGroup.
    ft.replace(android.R.id.content, newFragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    // Commit the transaction
    ft.commit();    
}
```

You can use the ListAdapter's `getItemId()` method to refer to the ID of a player. Use the `ListView.setAdapter()` method to use your own `ListAdapter` for the `ListView`. The `ListAdapter` is responsible for maintaining the data backing this list and for producing a view to represent an item in that data set. [This](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) tutorial describes how you can write your own `ArrayAdapter` for a `ListView`.

In your `ListAdapter`, you override the `getItemId()` method and return the ID of the player. The `PlayerDetailFragment` can then take the id to retrieve data from a database.

I have no experience working with ViewPagers, so I can't help with that.